# How to specify particular slice/subcube is particular value for all Measures in MDX Query?

Tags: mdx

Say I have a calculated member on a hierarchy within a query

```
WITH 

MEMBER [Dept].[Dept].[Home Dept] AS
       [Dept].[Dept].&[Cooking] + [Dept].[Dept].&[Cleaning]

SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[Some Amount]
} ON 0,

NON EMPTY 
{
    [Dept].[Dept].[Dept].MEMBERS 
    + [Dept].[Dept].[Home Dept] 
    - [Dept].[Dept].&[Cooking] 
    - [Dept].[Dept].&[Cleaning]
} ON 1

FROM 
    [MyCube]
```

How can I specify that if I slice with another Hierarchy (say `[X].[X].[Something]`) the result of the tuple `([X].[X].[Something], [Dept].[Dept].[Home Dept], [Measures].[All])`, everything along this tuple is `particular value`.

so if I add the filter

```
WHERE
(
   [X].[X].[Something]
)
```

to the above, it should return `particular value`.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave a simple example of the numbers (e.g. draw a 3x1 grid). Also, tell us if [X].[X].[Something] is the only dimension you'll be using, or if it could be any one of several other dimensions.

Comment: @MagnusSmith Thank you - will create an example and add it to the question